# how to check a given string is a timezone instance

Tags: django, datetime

how can i check a `given string is a timezone instance` , say i have argument value namely 'date' in a method, i want check it as a timezone instance or timezone aware instance before return it, i have trid the following, but it failed

```
def get_date(date=None):
   if not isinstance(date, timezone):
       raise ValidationError('please provide timezone aware date type value')
```

it shows the error,

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

how can check a string value as timezone aware date instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [is_aware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.is_aware) or [is_naive](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.is_naive)

```
from django.utils.timezone import is_aware
if not is_aware(date):
    raise ValidationError('please provide timezone aware date type value')
```

Comment: assume, my `date` field is optional,then what i shoud set as default value?because if i set `date=None` then it will not work.

Comment: Why not check the value on `None`? `if date and is_naive(date): raise ValidationError()`